# iMacros TAG CONTENT doesn't works

Tags: imacros

I want to put text into the input on the page, but it doesn't belong to any valid form. How I can do it?

I tried:

```
TAG SELECTOR='<selector>' CONTENT='<content>'
```

and

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="selector" KEYS=[keycodes]
```

But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you provide the html markup section that you're trying to input text into?

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

`CSS Selectors are only available in EVENT command with imacros add-on for firefox. But one need iMacros pro v11 to use CSS Selectors in TAG command.`

So why cant you just do this

1. First, **use imacros plugin in firefox** for this, then go to **Record -> Record Options -> Enable Experimental Event Recording Mode**.
2. Then click record button and click the input box where you want to paste, the selector for the input tag will be recorded like so.

`EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="html>body>div:nth-of-type(2)>div:nth-of-type(2)>input" BUTTON=0`

3. Now what you actually need is only the selector address, this will be the path of the input tag where you want to place your text. So next you will paste the selector from the previous step into the below code.

   ```
   SET !CLIPBOARD "text that is going to be placed in the input tag"
   EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="html>body>div:nth-of-type(2)>div:nth-of-type(2)>input" CHAR="v" MODIFIERS="ctrl"
   ```

So lets check the above code on what is going on.

**Line1:** We set the clipboard variable of imacros to whatever text you want to insert.

**Line2:** Then the event tag is going to select the input tag will the selector that we manually inserted, Then we trigger a **Ctrl + v** through Imacros and the text is gonna get pasted.

I hope my explanation was clear and consise and hope it helped with your issue.

**References:**

1. [How to select all copy and paste in imacros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42795325/how-to-select-all-copy-and-paste-in-imacros)
2. [How to extract text using CSS Selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171119/how-to-extract-text-using-css-selectors-in-imacros)
3. [imacros selector discussion](http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=26085)